# dask_geopandas: GeoDataFrame with only geometry column

Tags: python, dask, geopandas, shapely, dask-dataframe

Using `geopandas` one can do:

```py
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas as gpd

points = [Point(0,0)]
gser = gpd.GeoSeries(points)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gser.values)
```

If I had a `dask_geopandas.GeoSeries` what would be the equivalent lines in `dask_geopandas`? It seems that one can not use directly the `dask_geopandas.GeoDataFrame` constructor and has to rely on the staticmethods but can't see any suitable one.

EDIT:

To clarify: I have a `dask_geopandas.GeoSeries` (no `geopandas.GeoSeries` anywhere), how could I create a `dask_geopandas.GeoDataFrame` that only contains one column, a geometry column, whose values come from the `dask_geopandas.GeoSeries`?

Snippet that doesn't work:

```py
dgser # is a dask_geopandas.GeoSeries
dgdf = dask_geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geometry=dgser.values)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this use case is already covered by `to_frame()` method of dask Series.

```py
dask_geodataframe = dask_series.to_frame()
```

That should be enough, the path through the vanilla dask dataframe is not necessary.

Comment: and `to_frame` also accepts a `name` argument, awesome!

Comment: `dask.dataframe.Series.to_frame()` [API](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.Series.to_frame.html)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `from_geopandas`:

```py
from dask_geopandas import from_geopandas
from shapely.geometry import Point
from geopandas import GeoSeries, GeoDataFrame

points = [Point(0,0)]
gser = GeoSeries(points)
gdf = GeoDataFrame(geometry=gser.values)
dgdf = from_geopandas(gdf, npartitions=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out (although I wish there was a built-in method for this):

```py
dgser # is a dask_geopandas.GeoSeries
ddf = dgser.to_dask_dataframe()
ddf.columns = ["geometry"]
dgfg = dask_geopandas.from_dask_dataframe(ddf)
```

Comment: I agree this feature seems like an obvious improvement. A request would probably be welcome on the [project issues](https://github.com/geopandas/dask-geopandas/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen), esp if you’re able to contribute an implementation :)